What is the justification for replacing $x(t)$ with a constant value in the ladder word problem?
I am working on the following problem from Huettenmueller, R. Business calculus demystified. McGraw-Hill.

A 20-foot ladder is leaning against a wall. The base of the ladder slips and the top of the ladder starts to slide against the wall. When the base of the ladder is 12 feet from the wall, it is moving at the rate of 5 feet per second. At this instant, how fast is the top of the ladder moving?


Since $y$ and $x$ depend on time, I can represent them as functions which depend on $t$, i.e. y(t) and x(t).
Looking at the picture, the following equation holds:
$$x^2(t) + y^2(t) = 20^2$$
And from that equation, I can see:
$$y(t) =\sqrt{20^2 - x^2(t)}$$
However, in order to use the information appearing in the problem, replacing $x(t)$ by 12 seems to make sense:
$$y(t) =\sqrt{20^2 - 12^2}$$
Now, here is my issue; after simplifying, I get:
$$y(t) = 16$$
This would imply that, for example, $y(0) = 16$ and $y(2) = 16$. That is, $y$ is a constant function which returns 16 for every possible input. And that's clearly not true.
What I am missing in these last steps ? Is it possible to replace a function like x(t) with a constant value ? What's the justification behind that operation.

You're treating $y$ as though it was a function of $x$. You need to substitute $x(t)$ into the equation so that $x$ is gone and only $t$ remains in the expression for $f(t)$.

The substitution you suggest is in fact not correct.
As you correctly stated, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are functions of time and are subject to change as time passes.
The exact information given in the statement of the exercise is:
"When the base of the ladder is 12 feet from the wall, it is moving at the rate of 5 feet per second."
If we try and "translate" the statement above into something that can more suitably work with equations, we would say that at some time $t_0$, the following holds:
$$x(t_0) = 12 ft. \quad \text{and} \quad v(t_0) = 5 \frac{ft.}{s},$$
where we may define $v(t)$ as the speed of the ladder at time $t$.
Hence the equation you correctly deduced in fact only gives: $$y(t_0) = \sqrt{(20 \: ft.)^2-x(t_0)^2},$$
meaning only $y(t_0) = 16 ft.$, and not $y(t) = 16 ft.$, the later (incorrecty) suggesting that $y(t) = 16 ft.$ $\textbf{at every moment in time} \: t$.

Note that $x = 12$ ft for a precise value of $t$ (which is unknown), not in general, so that $y = 16$ ft for the same $t$ only. But you needn't compute $y$ or the said value of $t$ in the end, because $$\dot{y} = -\frac{x\dot{x}}{\sqrt{20^2-x^2}},$$ with $x = 12$ ft and $\dot{x} = 5$ ft/s at the considered time $t$.
